# Java. Extracting integers from bits in a byte array not fitting the byte boundary

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I have the following array of bytes:
01010110 01110100 00100101 01001011

These bytes are broken into two groups to encode seven integers. I know that the first group consists of 3 values 4 bits each (0101 0110 0111) that represent numbers 5,6,7. The second group consists of 4 values 5 bits each (01000 01001 01010 01011), which represent integers 8,9,10, and 11.

To extract the integers, I am currently using the following approach. Convert the array into a binary string:

```
public static String byteArrayToBinaryString(byte[] byteArray)
    {
    String[] arrayOfStrings = new String[byteArray.length];

    for(int i=0; i<byteArray.length; i++)
    {
        arrayOfStrings[i] = byteToBinaryString(byteArray[i]);
    }

    String bitsetString = "";
    for(String testArrayStringElement : arrayOfStrings)
    {
        bitsetString += testArrayStringElement;
    }

    return bitsetString;
}

// Taken from here: http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/converting-large-byte-array-to-binary-string
public static String byteToBinaryString(byte byteIn) 
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("00000000");

    for (int bit = 0; bit < 8; bit++) 
    {
        if (((byteIn >> bit) & 1) > 0) 
        {
            sb.setCharAt(7 - bit, '1');
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Then, I split the binary string into 2 substrings: 12 characters and 20 characters. Then I split each substring into new substrings, each of which has length that equals the number of bits. Then I convert each sub-substring into an integer.

It works but a byte array representing thousands of integers takes 30 seconds to a minute to extract.

I am a bit at a loss here. How do I do this using bitwise operators?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I assume you have an understanding of the basic [bit operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation) and how to express them in Java.

---

Use a pencil to draw a synthetic picture of the problem

```
 byte 0     byte 1     byte 2     byte 3
01010110   01110100   00100101   01001011
\__/\__/   \__/\______/\___/\______/\___/
 a   b      c     d      e     f      g
```

To extract *a*, *b* and *c* we need to do the following

```
   a          b          c

 byte 0     byte 0     byte 1
01010110   01010110   01110100
\.  \.     ||||||||   \.  \.  
  '\  '\   XXXX||||     '\  '\
0.. 0101   0.. 0110   0.. 0111

  Shift       And       Shift
```

In Java

```
int a = byteArray[0] >>> 4, b = byteArray[0] & 0xf, c = byteArray[1] >>> 4;
```

The other values *d*, *e*, *f* and *g* are computed similarly but some of them require to read two bytes from the array (*d* and *f* actually).

```
          d                      e

   byte 1    byte 2            byte 2
  01110100  00100101          00100101
  ||||\\\\  |                 |\\\\\
  XXXX \\\\ |                 X \\\\\
        \\\\|                    \\\\\
  0..   01000                    01001
```

To compute *d* we need to isolate the least four bits of byte 1 with `byteArray[1] & 0xf` then make space for the bit from byte 2 with `(byteArray[1] & 0xf) << 1`, extract that bit with `byteArray[1] >>> 7` and finally merge together the result.

```
int d = (byteArray[1] & 0xf) << 1 | byteArray[2] >>> 7;
int e = (byteArray[2] & 0x7c) >>> 2;
int f = (byteArray[2] & 0x3) << 3 | byteArray[3] >>> 5;
int g = byteArray[3] & 0x1f;
```

---

When you are comfortable with handling bits operations you may consider generalizing the function that extract the integers.

I made function `int extract(byte[] bits, int[] sizes, int[] res)`, that given an array of bytes `bits`, an array of sizes `sizes`, where the even indices hold the size of the integers to extract in bits and the odd indices the number of integers to extract, and an output array `res` large enough to hold all the integers in output, extracts from `bits` all the integers expressed by `sizes`.
It returns the number of integers extracted.

For example the original problem can be solved as

```
int res[] = new int[8];
byte bits[] = new byte[]{0x56, 0x74, 0x25, 0x4b};

//Extract 3 integers of 4 bits and 4 integers of 5 bits
int ints = BitsExtractor.extract(bits, new int[]{4, 3,  5, 4}, res);
```

---

```
public class BitsExtractor
{
    public static int extract(byte[] bits, int[] sizes, int[] res)
    {

        int currentByte = 0;            //Index into the bits array
        int intProduced = 0;            //Number of ints produced so far
        int bitsLeftInByte = 8;         //How many bits left in the current byte
        int howManyInts = 0;            //Number of integers to extract 

        //Scan the sizes array two items at a time
        for (int currentSize = 0; currentSize < sizes.length - 1; currentSize += 2)
        {
            //Size, in bits, of the integers to extract
            int intSize = sizes[currentSize];

            howManyInts += sizes[currentSize+1];

            int temp = 0;                   //Temporary value of an integer
            int sizeLeft = intSize;         //How many bits left to extract 


            //Do until we have enough integer or we exhaust the bits array
            while (intProduced < howManyInts && currentByte <= bits.length)
            {
                //How many bit we can extract from the current byte
                int bitSize = Math.min(sizeLeft, bitsLeftInByte);               //sizeLeft <= bitsLeftInByte ? sizeLeft : bitsLeftInByte;
                //The value to mask out the number of bit extracted from
                //The current byte (e.g. for 3 it is 7)
                int byteMask = (1 << bitSize) - 1;
                //Extract the new bits (Note that we extract starting from the
                //RIGHT so we need to consider the bits left in the byte)
                int newBits = (bits[currentByte] >>> (bitsLeftInByte - bitSize)) & byteMask;

                //Create the new temporary value of the current integer by
                //inserting the bits in the lowest positions
                temp = temp << bitSize | newBits;

                //"Remove" the bits processed from the byte
                bitsLeftInByte -= bitSize;

                //Is the byte has been exhausted, move to the next
                if (bitsLeftInByte == 0)
                {
                    bitsLeftInByte = 8;
                    currentByte++;
                }

                //"Remove" the bits processed from the size
                sizeLeft -= bitSize;

                //If we have extracted all the bits, save the integer
                if (sizeLeft == 0)
                {
                    res[intProduced++] = temp;
                    temp = 0;
                    sizeLeft = intSize;
                }
            }
        }

        return intProduced;

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Margaret! This is an awesome answer. I have modified your code a bit to extract an array of integers instead of the number of values, and it works as a charm. I need to check whether the code works if the size of integers exceeds three bytes, for example. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well I did the first group , the second can be done in similar fashion

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
        //an example 32 bits like your example
        byte[] bytes = new byte[4];
        bytes[0] = 31;//0001 1111
        bytes[1] = 54;//0011 0110
        bytes[2] = 67;
        bytes[3] = 19;
        //System.out.println(bytes[0]);
        int x = 0;
        int j = -1; // the byte number
        int k = 0; // the bit number in that byte
        int n = 0; // the place of the bit in the integer we are trying to read
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {

            if (i < 12) { //first group 
                if (i % 8 == 0) {
                    j++;
                    k = 0;

                }
                if (i % 4 == 0) {

                    x = 0;
                    n = 0;
                }

                byte bit = (byte) ((bytes[j] & (1 << (7 - k))) >> (7 - k));
                System.out.println("j is :" + j + " k is :" + k + "  " + bit);
                x = x | bit << (3 - n);
                if ((i + 1) % 4 == 0) {
                    System.out.println(x);
                }
                k++;
                n++;

            } else {

            }

        }

    }
```

It's a bit tricky because you are trying to encode an integer on less than what java allocates (8 bits). So I had to take each bit and "construct" the int from them

To get each bit

```
byte bit = (byte) ((bytes[j] & (1 << (7 - k))) >> (7 - k));
```

this takes the byte we are at and does `And` operation. For example I want the 3rd bit of the 1st byte, I do

```
bytes[0] &  1 << (7 - 3)
```

but this gives me an integer encoded over 8 bits, so I still have to shift it to get that single bit with `>> (7 - 3)`

Then I just `Or` it with `x` (the int we are trying to decode). All while putting it at the right position with `<< (3 - n)` . 3 because your integer is encoded over 4 bits

Try running the code and reading the output.

I am honestly not sure if this is the best way, but I believe it's at least faster than dealing with Strings